# Send XON XOFF data to a COM port using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some test with a EPSON FISCAL PRINTER FP81II.

I installed also EPSON TM VIRTUAL DRIVER PORT to route a custom COMx port to USB.
I've assigned COM5 to my fiscal printer.

Then i've enabled XON-XOFF protocol in my printer.

Then I do some test with with class found on the web:

```
$test = new xonxoff();

$test->set_serial("4"); //<--- 4 cause 4+1 = 5 like docs explain

$test->simple_ticket();
```

CLASS:

```
class xonxoff {

    function __construct() {

        $this->serial = '0';
        $this->_open = false;
    }

    public function set_serial($dev) {
        // su Windows automaticamente esso viene aumentato di 1;

        $this->serial = $dev;
    }

    public function open_ticket() {
        $this->_send('K');
        // nulla
    }

    public function set_cashier($user = '') {
        // imposto il nome del casiere
        //$this->_send('O1');
    }

    public function descri_ticket($descr = '') {
        // stampa rigo descrittivo
        $this->_send('"' . $descr . '"@');
    }

    public function close_ticket($d = '1') {
        $this->_close_port();
    }

    public function open_drawer($d = '1') {
        // apertura cassetto
        $this->_close_port();
    }

    public function row_ticket($amount, $descr = '', $vat = '', $row = '') {
        // vendita articoli
        // il formato dell'importo deve essere senza punti e virgole e con 2 decimali
        $formato_ammount = number_format($amount, 2, '', '');
        $this->_send('"' . $descr . '"' . $formato_ammount . 'H1R');
    }

    public function pay_ticket($cash = '', $descr = '') {
        // pagamento
        $this->_send('1T');
    }

    public function simple_ticket($amount) {
        // Esempio di scontrino completo con pagamento contanti
        // senza descrizioni, una cosa veramente minimale
        $this->open_ticket();
        $this->row_ticket($amount);
        $this->pay_ticket();
        $this->close_ticket();
    }

    public function fiscal_report() {
        // Stampa rapporto fiscale Z10
        $this->_send('z1Fc');
        // Chiusura rapporto fiscale Z10
        $this->_send('');
        $this->_close_port();
    }

    protected function _tag_data($data) {
        $x = 32 + strlen($data);
        return chr($x) . $data;
    }

    protected function _crc($data) {
        $x = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); $i++) {
            $x+=ord($data[$i]);
        }
        return str_pad(strtoupper(DecHex($x)), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    protected function _open_port() {
        // setting serial port rs232
        $sysname = substr(php_uname(), 0, 3);
        if ($sysname == "Lin") {
            if (is_numeric(substr($this->serial, 0, 1))) {
                $_serial = '/dev/ttyS' . intval(substr($this->serial, 0, 1));
            } else {
                $_serial = $this->serial;
            }
            exec('stty -F ' . $_serial . ' baud=9600 +cs8 -parenb +cstopb clocal -crtscts -ixon -ixoff');
        } elseif ($sysname == "Win") {
            if (is_numeric(substr($this->serial, 0, 1))) {
                $_serial = 'COM' . intval(substr($this->serial, 0, 1) + 1);
            } else {
                $_serial = $this->serial;
            }
            exec('MODE ' . $_serial . ' BAUD=9600 DATA=8 PARITY=N STOP=1 XON=OFF');
        } else {
            trigger_error("Il Sistema operativo non risulta essere windows o linux
                           ci sono problemi per settare la porta RS232", E_USER_ERROR);
            exit();
        }
        // end setting serial

        $this->_handle = fopen($_serial, "r+");
        $this->_open = true;
    }

    protected function _send($data) {
        if (!$this->_open) {
            $this->_open_port();
        }

        fwrite($this->_handle, $data);
        sleep(1);
    }

    protected function _close_port() {
        if ($this->_open) {
            fclose($this->_handle);
            $this->_open = false;
        }
    }

}
```

I've tested the script using WAMP. All work great.

Next step is to put the script in a online server. Then execute the script from a client PC with the print connected on it. The problem is that the script, running on the server, expected that COM5 is of the server (not the client).

So my question are:
1. is it possible to send data to a COM in a client PC?
2. If not, i think this can be fixed using javascript instead PHP but i don't know if javascript can access to COM ports... and nothing found on the web.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: JavaScript running in the browser can not access anything even close to a COM port.

Comment: I've made my own driver for that device specifically, though your code doesn't seems to be javascript. Did you know that epson has an **official** javascript library? If you're planning to use javascript directly, you should rather set the FP81II to work by hosting the web service instead, otherwise you **can't** directly use it through the browser, you need a middleware (a node server or a php server). Since you're italian you can check the official documentation available directly in the epson website: https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5816&ml_lang=it

Comment: hi @briosheje, i've already found this docs. Yes the code i've posted is a PHP example that work ok if the printer is directly attached to the server....but next step in my project is to put the web app online so ... printer is not attached to server but to client.... and javascript maybe can help instead PHP. but epson docs are not very easy to understand. How your webapp work with this FP81II?

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini my application takes advantage of the web service hosted by the FP81II. There is a configuration for the printer that will not look at any COM port, but will just create a web server accessible on the local area network. My library just calls the web service over the network and perform operations without relying on any physical connection (since it's in a local network). If you're not planning to use the web service way, you **can't** do that with a web browser only, you need a middleware and a "server" directly connected to the FP81II through any kind of serial port.

Comment: let me know if I understand: you have set your printer with TCP/IP connection and assigned ad address, for example: 192.168.1.100. Then you uploaded your web server inside the printer inside 192.168.1.100/www folder? Then you simply send command like 192.168.1.100/www/myapp.php?data1=value&data2=value2&... .... So I can assign my 192.168.1.100 to a public IP using for example duckdns.org service to access on it?

Comment: @phuzi is correct.  You have create an ActiveX control which only works in IE or build a local web service at 127.0.0.1 and hope you don't run into cross domain issues to get around this on the local machine.

Comment: @briosheje do you use fp81II with XON-XOFF enabled? cause i've tried other scripts that use ESC/P protocol like mike42/escpos-php ... but in this case i don't received feedback by the printer... i can communicate only with xon-xoff enabled.

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini Not sure, I didn't follow the project much further, I was just the guy who made the javascript library, the only relevant info I have is that the web server was enabled. Perhaps you should contact Epson directly, they have a great developers support ;)